# VB.NET Selenium WebDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes is not suppressing 'WebDriverTimeoutException'

Tags: .net, vb.net, selenium

I am trying to ignore the WebDriverTimeoutException when using an ExplicitWait in Selenium, like so.

```
Dim wait As New WebDriverWait(driver, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10))
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(GetType(WebDriverTimeoutException))
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("foo")))
```

This works fine for other Selenium exceptions, such as NoSuchElementException. But with WebDriverTimeoutExceptions, it is not being ignored.

I realize I could just use a Try-Catch block, but why is this not working as intended?

Comment: What should happen if your desired element isn't found within the 10s you specified? That's when the timeout exception is thrown. It's intentional.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code below, there are some fundamental issues:

```
Dim wait As New WebDriverWait(driver, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10))
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(GetType(WebDriverTimeoutException))
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("foo")))
```

When you induce **`WebDriverWait`** with the **`ExpectedConditions`** clause set to **`InvisibilityOfElementLocated`** which effectively means the `element` the element must present in the `HTML DOM` and you want to wait for its invisibility. If you look at the source code (I looked at Python) of **`InvisibilityOfElementLocated`**, it is defined as:

```python
try:
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator), False)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
    # In the case of NoSuchElement, returns true because the element is
    # not present in DOM. The try block checks if the element is present
    # but is invisible.
    # In the case of StaleElementReference, returns true because stale
    # element reference implies that element is no longer visible.
    return True
```

Which means **`InvisibilityOfElementLocated`** internally handles **`NoSuchElementException`** and **`StaleElementReferenceException`**, but not **`WebDriverTimeoutExceptions`**. Once the `timespan` you mention while initializing the `WebDriverWait` instance ceases to exist, in absence of the `element` which was to be invisible, you see the **`WebDriverTimeoutExceptions`**

So fundamentally, the result of adding **`WebDriverTimeoutException`** to the **`IgnoreExceptionTypes`** while **`ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated()`** is **nil**.